# Mono.fromCallable vs Mono.fromSupplier

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two methods, but they seem similar to me. Even javadocs are pretty much the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is between the parameters you use in the methods.

If you use a [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), it computes a result or throws an exception if unable to do so.
If you use a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) you get a result.

There is also [another nice post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215917/callable-vs-supplier-interface-in-java) where this topic is discussed.